# Adding string values (varchars) to MySQL table without quotation marks with Django/Python

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble entering string values into a MySQL table *without* quotation marks via Django/Python.

Currently, I have the following schema:

```
 Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
 ticker           | varchar(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
```

In my population script, I have `values[0]`, which references the first value in an array, previously split on comma.

```
>>> values[0], type(values[0])
('"AAPL"', <type 'str'>)`
```

I then assign this value to my model and save it:

```
fi = MarketData()
fi.ticker = values[0]
fi.save()
```

In the database table, this value is stored with double quotes:

```
+--------+
| ticker |
--------+
| "AAPL" |
+--------+
```

This prevents my from joining on a separate table where the primary key is also the ticker, *and* the values in that able are stored without any type of quotations.

My Django model:

```
ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, db_column='ticker')
```

I have tried converting the double strings to single, and escaping, but haven't had much luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the quotation using `strip`

```
new_value = value[0].strip('"')  # for double quoted strings
```

You can also do it for single-quoted strings:

```
new_value = value[0].strip("'")  # for single-quoted strings
```

Then store it in the database.